Dark current in InGaAs vs Silicon CMOS camera sensors
It is well known that thermal vibrations may excite electrons across a bandgap in a photo-detecting material, and thus generate photoelectrons even when no incident light is incident. When imaging, especially in low-light conditions, this effect manifests and is known as "dark current noise".
This may be a basic question, but I hope to clarify it nonetheless because Google wasn't too informative for me:
Are InGaAs photodetectors more sensitive to temperature, and therefore more susceptible to dark current noise, than Silicon photodetectors?
That's probably the reason why virtually all InGaAs cameras have some sort of cooling mechanism. It also makes sense, because the SWIR range for InGaAs sensors (900-1700nm) means their bandgap will be lower, and therefore, it will be "easier" to generate thermal electrons given a temperature. I'd just like to confirm this is true. Thank you!

more current per area, or more current per sensitivity? (An InGaAs detector is usually smaller at the same sensitivity than Si, if I remember correctly). But generally you seem right – the InGaAs bandgap is small and direct, meaning it doesn't take much energy to get a charge carrier across
